# Remove class after adding it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to remove a class that is added right after the user click on a div.

I mean, after the div is clicked, I want the class to be removed.

https://codepen.io/jinzagon/pen/XWdVbgo

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.section').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $responsiveDiv = $('.response')
       $responsiveDiv.addClass('clicked');
       setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.assign($a.attr('href'));
     }, 6700); 
    
    }); 

  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use setTimeout postpone remove

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.section').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $responsiveDiv = $('.response')
      $responsiveDiv.addClass('clicked');

      setTimeout(function() {
        $responsiveDiv.removeClass('clicked');
      }, 1000); 

      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.assign($a.attr('href'));
      }, 6700); 
    
    }); 

  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has a `toggleClass` function that you can use. [Link](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Here it is in your example - when you click the section the background color will toggle (for ease of observation).

```css
.clicked {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="section">
    <div class="response">
        This is a response
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.section').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $responsiveDiv = $('.response');
      $responsiveDiv.toggleClass('clicked');
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `toggleClass()` for this

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.section').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $responsiveDiv = $('.response')
       $responsiveDiv.toggleClass('clicked'); //Toggle class instead of Add
       setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.assign($a.attr('href'));
     }, 6700); 
    
    }); 

  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With **javascript** you can achieve this using `.classList.remove("foo");`

Read more about [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
function addClassThenRemove(){
  // grab h1 element
  let h1Element = document.querySelector('h1')
  // add class to the element
  h1Element.classList.add('new')
  setTimeout(function(){
    //after 2 seconds remove class new
    h1Element.classList.remove('new')
  }, 2000)
}
```

```css
.new{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>

<button onClick="addClassThenRemove()">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. One way to remove class name as you use jQuery is `.removeClass()`
   Reference https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/
2. Another way which I prefer is to toggle class name. Here is a reference
   jQuery: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp
   Vanilla Javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp
3. Last but not least, the easiest way is to set the className equal to none. As an example in JavaScript
   `document.querySelector('.clicked').className = '';`